# Cant segue new facebook auth user with Parse

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I'm registering new users under my application that uses facebook API and Parse. The users are being created without segueing to another view. Unfortunately, if I try to segue for a next view the user is created without the name and email info. I know this runs in background so i need a solution to know when the execution is finished. Any ideas?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    FBSDKProfile.enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange(true)
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if let access = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() {
        PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithAccessToken(access, block: {
            (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if user != nil {
                println("already registred user")
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("firstView", sender: self)
            } else {
                println("Uh oh. There was an error logging in.")
            }
        })
    }
}

@IBAction func fbLoginButtonTouchUpInside (sender: AnyObject) {
    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], block: { (user, error) in
        if let user = user {
            User.updateUserInfo()
            println("new user")


            //THIS SEGUE IS CRASHING
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("newUserSegue", sender: self)

        } else {
            println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Since your segues are in the closures they should only be called after the task is complete and the results are available in the closure. I'm confused by your code comment "//This SEGUE IS CRASHING" - What error message are you getting?

Comment: its segueing. but with the segue it isnt saving the new user data. there is no  error msg. the point is how to know when the task is completed?

Comment: The task is completed before the code in the closure executes, that's how the closure knows if the task was successful or if an object is not nil. You know the task is complete because you're assigned a constant with user = user. You're question should be more about how to make a Facebook Graph API request to get a person's name & email and update the parse user with that information.

Comment: Ok, i think i'm not being clear.

- WithOUT Segue: the user is being created and saved into Parse WITH email and name  

- With Segue: user is being saved into Parse WITHOU email and name.

Let me put in this way: where in the code should i performSegueWithIdentifier?

Comment: what is User.updateUserInfo() ? If that is spawning another background task then you should add a completion handler to it and perform the segue inside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that I was running another background task inside

`PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions`

The solution was to add a completion handler to `User.updateUserInfo()` and perform the segue inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. AFAK you must perform on main thread that is why it is crashing:

`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
         self.performSegueWithIdentifier("newUserSegue", sender: self)
    }`